Expectations of eMMC performance as eMMC device is worn down
As an eMMC device is worn down, should I expect its performance (e.g. read/write latency/throughput) to degrade as well?
If yes, then what kind of pattern should I expect it to follow? For example, some kind of linear relationship with one of the values at https://wiki.friendlyelec.com/wiki/index.php/EMMC, or a sharp decline near its end of life?
If no, then why not?

I would guess (Note: Guess!) that there is a somewhat sharp decline when the eMMC has some sort of 'onboard' storage controller. Once all sectors are "Dirty" the controller has to start shuffeling data around (clear to all 1s, move/write data) and doo the housekeeping.
